# How to get $fault variable as it is in the ErrorMessage in OSB proxy message flow?

Tags: fault, osb, oracle-fusion-middleware

In the validation stage in my stage error handler, I can see that the $fault variable is populating with a proper xml which is the fault offcourse. I want to assign this entire xml "AS IT IS" in my ErrorMessage and concat it with a string. I tried the below:
fn:concat('myString',fn-bea:inlinedXML($fault/*))

Now my error message has the string plus it is showing the fault in some other format. An immediate response will be appreciated.

Comment: What is - some other format ? Could you be more precise please. Edit your question with samples of current format and expected format.So that it will be easy for others to understand the problem and help you.

Comment: @Habin the current format is coming similar to this:

<Mystring.>BEA-382505OSB Validate action failed validationInvalid date value: wrong type: string value '' is not a valid enumeration value for *** in namespace *** string value '' is not a valid enumeration value for *** in namespace *** 

The expected format is this:

<con:fault xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context"><con:errorCode>BEA-382505</con:errorCode><con:reason>OSB Validate action failed validation</con:reason><con:details>
Apologies for the late reply and thanks for reverting.

Answer (score 0):

I got the expected format by assigning the below to my ErrorMessage:

fn:concat('myString',fn-bea:serialize($fault/*))

Comment: Just be aware that `serialize()` can be slow for large xml payloads. Putting it in an error handler might be risky for high volume services.

Comment: Hi @TrentBartlem Thanks for the revert. We are mostly using **serialize()** in our error handlers for most of the services while getting the ErrorMessage. What should be the otherwise approach?

Comment: Soap faults are not too bad (although you might want to just select the fault message and detail, and/or truncate parts if you receive a 200k stack trace from a Java web service or something) - you can use an async publish if you want, although that has its own issues). The real danger is using serialize() on request messages and response messages, because you really don't have a lot of control over the size of them.

Comment: Thanks @TrentBartlem :)